# What happens to the items in your pet's inventory when your crystalline aura expires?

Tags: lost-ark

What happens to the items in your pet's inventory when your crystalline aura expires?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They become locked and you receive a move all button that lets you transfer them to your regular character's inventory.